# RabbitMQ UI is not coming up after upgrading from RabbitMQ 3.11.0 to RabbitMQ 3.12.12

Tags: rabbitmq

I was using RabbitMQ 3.11.0 with Erlang 25.1. Recently I upgraded RabbitMQ version from 3.11.0 to 3.12.12. My application is running properly but when I am trying to load RabbitMQ UI, it is not coming up completely.

Comment: some server side logs would help